# error: resource style/AppTheme.NoActionBar (aka com.example.musicstream:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) not found

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I am creating a music player but I cant seem to fix the error what do I need to do?

I tried looking it up online but couldn't fix it myself , I am really new to coding.

This is my **manifest** file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.musicstream">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Search"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".PlaySongActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my **style.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#795496</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#7e20cb</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#795496</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This error is because Android Studio cannot resolve the symbol "`@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar`" within your activity.

Replacing it with `android:theme="@style/AppTheme` solves the error.

Answer (score 0):

change `"@style/AppTheme"` to `@style/AppThemeTheme.AppCompat`

Comment: This answer was automatically tagged "low quality". As explained in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ("Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."), please edit your answer to tell the OP what he's doing wrong, how you reasoned and what your code is about, to show that you understood the question and to make benefit both the OP and future visitors.